# Determine if a function is integrable.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

We define Riemann function

$ f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{q} & x=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q},\left(\frac{p}{q}\text{ reduced}\right)\\
0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases} $

and Dirichlet function

$ D\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases} $

I have to determine which of the following is integrable over $ [0,1] $ :

$$1.D(x)f(x)\ \  2. D(\sqrt{2}x)\ \ 3. f(\sqrt{2}x)\ \ 4.D(\sqrt{2}x)f(x) $$

Here's what I tried:

$1$. I know that Riemann function is integrable in $ [0,1] $ and basically $ D(x)f(x)= f(x) $ in $ [0,1] $ so the first one is integrable.

$2$. I claim that $ D\left(\sqrt{2}x\right) $ is not integrable, because if it was then we would get that $ D(x) $ is integrable in $ [0,\sqrt{2}] $ and :

$ \intop_{0}^{1}D\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\intop_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}D\left(x\right) $

But it's false. so the second is not integrable.

As for 3, I think that its integrable, because $ f $ is integrable in $ [0,\sqrt{2}] $ (is it? ) therefore $ f(\sqrt{2}x) $ is integrable in $ [0,1] $

And for the last one, I cannot determine.

I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, your function $f(x)$ is also called [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).